# How can you justify content like with `justify-content: space-between;` but using a table instead?

Tags: html, css

How can you justify content like with `justify-content: space-between;` but **without using flexbox** and using a table instead?

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Apples</td>
    <td>Blueberries</td>
    <td>Bananas</td>
    <td>Strawberries</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I would like for "Apples" to be flush left, "Strawberries" to be flush right and the spacing between the text items to be equal.

Using `text-align` with even column widths does **not** result in even spacing.

Comment: You can't. However, consider using CSS grid instead.

Answer (score 0):

`text-align: center` applied as a single CSS attribute can't work because each **td** has the `width` set to `auto`.

What you can do is to divide the width of each *td* by the amount of *td*'s you have:

```
td {
  width: calc(100% / NB_TD (in your case: 4);
  text-align: center;
}

td:first-child { // For 'Apple' aligned in the left
  text-align: left;
}

td:last-child { // For 'Strawberries' aligned in the right
  text-align: right
}
```

Comment: This does **not** work, unfortunately. Take a look at this codepen: https://codepen.io/leev2/pen/qBKbENP You will notice that Apples is not flush left and the spacing between Kiwi and Blueberries does not match the spacing between Bananas and Strawberries.

Comment: You changed your answer and so I updated the codepen. This strategy still does not work.